# Bing Visual Search Not Returning Image Tag properly

Tags: bing-api

Here is  my response from Bing API Visual Search(v7).

Expected Response :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-visual-search/reference/response-objects

Actual Response:

```
{
  "_type": "ImageKnowledge",
  "instrumentation": {
    "_type": "ResponseInstrumentation"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "displayName": "",
      "actions": [
        {
          "actionType": "MoreSizes"
        },
        {
          "actionType": "ImageById"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "image": {**strong text**
    "imageInsightsToken": "ccid_w4YMbjM9"
  },
  "imageQualityHints": [
    {
      "category": "UnknownFormat"
    }
  ],
  "debugInfo": {}
}
```

Can any one help?